# query two tables but select different columns depending on the value of field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables which contain orders. I need to check that the tables match up. The table look something like below,

**tblOrders_Sent**

```
Side   Tag     FxBuy  BuyAmount   FxCost CostAmount
B      CHFEUR  CHF    50          EUR    0
B      EURSEK  SEK    75          EUR    0
B      EURNOK  NOK    35          EUR    0
B      DKKEUR  DKK    20          EUR    0
S      CHFEUR  EUR    0           CHF    10    
S      EURSEK  EUR    0           SEK    20
S      EURNOK  EUR    0           NOK    40
```

**tblOrders_Recieved**

```
Tag        FxBuy  MktBuy    FxCost MktCost
EURNOK     NOK    35        EUR    0
DKKEUR     DKK    20        EUR    0
CHFEUR     CHF    50        EUR    0
EURSEK     SEK    75        EUR    0
EURNOK     EUR    0         NOK    40
EURSEK     EUR    0         SEK    20
CHFEUR     EUR    0         CHF    10
```

When the Side is "B" in the Orders_Sent table I need to check the BuyAmount against the MktBuy amount in the Orders_Recieved table. If the Side is "S" though I need to check the CostAmount vs the MktCost in the Orders_Recieved table. Is this possible or do I need to split the query into two seperate queries?

I'm using SQL Server 2012

**Desired Output**

```
FxBuy   FxCost   SentAmt   RecievedAmt  Diff
CHF     EUR      50        50           0
SEK     EUR      75        75           0
NOK     EUR      35        35           0
DKK     EUR      20        20           0
EUR     CHF      10        10           0
EUR     SEK      20        20           0
EUR     NOK      40        40           0
```

Comment: Can you add the expected result too?

Comment: What happens when you have multiple trades with the same currency pairs?  Either specify that this cannot happen or edit your question and describe how to handle this situation.

Comment: It is possible that there are multiple trades with the same currency pairs- sorry I should have pointed this out. The amounts though would always be different

Comment: I have updated the output I'm hoping to achieve

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Keyword is `case expression`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CASE keyword helps there. In your case as far as I understood the example it could look like this:

```
select 
    tblOrders_sent.fxBuy As FxBuy,
    tblorders_sent.fxCost As FxCost,
    tblorders_sent.buyamount as SentAmt,
    tblorders_received.mktbuy as ReceivedAmt,
    CASE Side WHEN 'B' THEN tblorders_sent.buyamount - tblorders_received.mktbuy END 
    tblorders_sent.costamount - tblorders_received.mktcost END AS diff
from tblOrders_sent 
inner join tblOrders_received on
    tblorders_sent.tag = tblorders_received.tag
```